How to fix Null check operator used on null value problem in dart
I am trying to follow a course on dart and it is a little outdated, I ran into the error, "Null check operator used on a null value" when trying to use a provider to make an instance of Bloc. I think the mistake is in the Provider section, but I don't know what it is. I already checked my Widget tree and it seems to be fine.
This is my main code
this is my app code
this is my login_screen code
this is my bloc code
this is my validator code
this is my provider code
I tried to fix this problem by watching videos and searching it up online to fix the problem, but it didn't help. Can someone pls help me fix this?

Welcome to SO!
please [edit] your question to include the code as text rather than as an image.

when I try to make it include the code it says the format is wrong.

If the editor is complaining that there's too much code, the solution is to post a smaller example that reproduces the problem. Alternatively, add more detail to explain the problem. If the problem is an error on only one line, you shouldn't need much code to reproduce it.

also, the problem you are mentioned is probably on a very specific piece of code so please only past that part here

The Error source is in the of method, You are using an exclamation operator (!) on a null value.
code image
recheck the value before putting an exclamation operator on it:
if (value == null){
  // handle that situation
}


I added this code in replacement to the current code in the of function:
static Bloc of(BuildContext context) {
final provider = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();
if (provider != null) {
return provider.bloc;
} else {
throw Exception('Provider not found in the widget tree');
}
}
} but now the error says Provider not found in Widget tree, so I need to find a way to  make the provider not null.
